# How to test if a specific link is clicked in PHP

Tags: php, hyperlink, click

I ve searched the answer to this question for days and I really need an answer..
so.. I have a database and a script that fetches the data from the database:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array ($query))
    {
        $name = $row['name'];
        $email = $row['email'];
        $tut_title = $row['tut_title'];
        $URL = $row['URL'];
        $description = $row ['description'];
        $Status = $row['Status'];
            echo "<tr>....<form action="samepage.php"><input type="submit"></form>
                ....
```

When clicked the submit form, same page is being loaded and an if(isset $POST['submit']) instruction comes up.
When this action occurs, I need to delete that specific record from the database.
(only data for the last entry will be stored)

So I need to store the data for that specific record somewhere inside that while, so I can use it to delete.. I don't know if you can make heads and tails out of my request but I will answer to any of your questions because I really don't know how to explain it better.

Thank you so much in advance guys.

Comment: Could you be more specific? What exactly are you trying to achieve. This code of yours isn't particularly useful. Do you get any errors reported?

Answer (score 0):

The record should have an AUTO_INCREMENT primary key - let's call it `$id`.

You add that identifier to the form:

```
echo '<form action="samepage.php?id=' . $id . '">';
```

You, as already said, check for the submit button being used using `isset()`. You there can fetch the identifier using `$_GET['id']` and construct a `DELETE` query.

Answer (score 0):

Lets if you have a data base and you have searched out and display some value and You want to delete some specific value when i clicked on hyper link associated with this element then use this code.

like :

```
Bk_name----Bk_Author   
C++         Y.V        Delete   
JAVA        Dietel     Delete
 .           .         .
 .           .         .

while( $info = mysql_fetch_assoc( $rs))
{
 echo" <a  href=task.php?delete=$info[bk_id]>Delete</a>";
 }
  //Now here on Hyperlink click event we will delete the associated data.

  if(isset($_REQUEST['delete']))
  {
   $delete = $_REQUEST['delete'];
   $query = mysql_query("DELETE FROM book WHERE bk_id= '$delete'")or   die(mysql_error());
   echo "Deleted";
}
```